# Is it the control board or is it the induction fan?

Tags: electrical, heating, forced-air

I've got an older Goodman (**GME80905CXAB**) that doesn't seem to heat. Blower motor turns on just fine for cool but not at all when there's a call for heat. I can confirm ~120 volts are going into the board from the transformer but I'm getting nothing for voltage from the board to the induction fan. Getting ~27 volts from the thermostat.

Seems like an issue with continuity but I'm not an electrician!

Is this likely to be an issue with the board?

[image: wiring-schematics]
[image: wiring-actual]

Comment: Can you post the wiring diagram for your unit?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I added images.

Comment: Can you try taking an ohms reading from the half-round pin on the inducer/igniter connector (that's the inducer-hot pin) to one of the neutral connections running down the right side of the upper part of the control board please?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel stuck at 1. For contrast if I check resistance on the inducer motor itself I get .007 and .020 from the transformer black to white.

Comment: Ah -- you should be getting that low resistance on the inducer motor -- the control board will read an open circuit, of course :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### It's likely the control board

Since the inducer motor's winding is still intact (as we know from it reading a low resistance), and no voltage makes it there, we can be pretty sure that your control board's failed; either it's not sequencing the inducer motor, or the relay that the board uses to the turn the inducer on and off has failed.  Either way, generic replacement control boards are available for most reasonably modern furnaces these days, so a decent HVAC tech should be able to get the furnace up and running in no time.

Comment: I was able to locate a replacement board - thank you! https://tinyurl.com/y4dus9d7

Comment: New board worked! Thank you!

Comment: P.S. seems to have been a bed inducer motor causing the boards to go out.

Comment: @NestorLedon -- maybe it had a short inside the winding causing it to draw excessive current on startup or something, glad it's sorted at least