# What could be damaging my furnace control board and/or what can I do to protect it?

Tags: electrical, heating, forced-air

I had an issue with a damaged control board a few months ago, replacing it worked, details here: [Is it the control board or is it the induction fan?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/204804/is-it-the-control-board-or-is-it-the-induction-fan/204931#204931)

A similar issue has now came up.

It's hit or miss if the **induction fan** comes on and sometimes when it does I see a **spark** coming from the **black wire** leading into the fan (image below). Sometimes it starts, sometimes it does not. This leads me to believe a similar malfunction is occurring with the board - it's just hasn't fully failed yet.

Lately my area has been getting **power surges** and I'm convinced it's related. I curious if there may be something wrong with the fan as well causing it to damage the board. Also the large blower the board is attached to **rocks WILDY** sometimes which I can't imagine is helpful.

Is there anything I can do to protect the equipment from surges and furthermore what tools can I use to further diagnose the issue?

*Fan*
[image]

*New Board*
[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Power surges can damaged most electronic equipment.  There are whole house power surge equipment that will protect from them.  Have read they getting less expensive now.  Any wire that sparks is usually bad, might just be loose connection, but should be check out.

Comment: I'll take a look at some whole house surge protectors. Better safe than sorry. I'll triple check for a weak connection.

Comment: Most of that stuff should not rock wildly if mounted correctly.  Most blowers are usually balanced, but could become unbalanced due to heavy dirt or broken pieces(fins), usually causing heavy vibration not rocking.

Comment: CHSPT2ULTRA - Eaton 7-in surge protection device requires a dedicate 50amp breaker in your panel.

Comment: @Fresh Codemonger  did google search on those surge protection devices for my own information.  Thought they might be a lot more expensive, but 100 to 200 dollars(US) for whole house is cheap when compared to 15/20 dollars(Can) per strip.

Comment: @crip659 yea that's a steal I'm having someone come install one for $350 USD. I didn't ask for the brand but I'll check. Also I don't think strips would work for the furnace. I've seen some warnings against using those for similar equipment.

Comment: My search was only amazon price, not install.  They seem simple to do.  Strips usually only good for plugins, TVs, computers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me it sounds more like bearings in the fan are going out. Or a bad electrical connection.
Surges that would cause a motor to jump around would blow just about every electronic device in the home up.

A motor that had bearing problems may spin up and when the bearings get hot start stalling or moving around.

If the motor was drawing two much current it could be damaging the board so I would not be looking at electrical surges from a service as much as for loose connections OR bearings going out.

Surge protection will not stop either problem from damaging the board.

Comment: How would you diagnose that?  Could you watch the temperature of the fan with a thermal camera?  Would you be able to hear the bearings being bad?

Comment: @fresh codemonger For a motor to jump around there would have to be serious connection problems or bearing problems. electrical surges that a surge suppressor would take out would toast all kinds of electronic circuits if large enough to diagnose, The first test fo do on a fan is a spin test with a good flick how long will it spin? Less than 10 seconds cold probably bad but hot it makes 3 seconds it gets obvious.  with the thermal camera but yes I have them also but cases like this the mechanical load is taking down the board due to overcurrent is my guess.

Comment: Seems to have been the induction fan. I got a new one and all seems well now.